# jquery - dynamically changing the option text is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

Please find the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qs008so7/

I have an option box in html and I am trying to set the option using jquery.
But its not working . Please find the code below.

If I call the code in console and I am able to see the expected html is getting returned. **Means , the changes are properly affected int he DOM but it is not getting reflected in UI.** . You can see my jfiddle .

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="test" id="test">
    <option value="0">Disabled</option>
    <option value="1">Enabled</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
setGivenOption(test,"Enabled");
setGivenOption(test,"Disabled");

function setGivenOption(elementId, option) {
    //Make all the old selections to null
    $(elementId).each(function () {
        $('option', this).each(function () {
            $(this).attr('selected', null);
        });
    });
    //set the given option
    $(elementId).find(">option:contains('" + option + "')").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, you should have a second thought about your parameter name `elementId`. In your code sample you are *not* passing an id, but rather an element itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where almost there: Try like this https://jsfiddle.net/q5886d5o/1/

**Update** after @Chips_100 comment

```
setGivenOption("test","Disabled");
setGivenOption("test","Enabled");

function setGivenOption(elementId, option) {
    //Make all the old selections to null
    $('#' + elementId).children('option').each(function () {
       $(this).attr('selected', null);
    });
    //set the given option
    $('#' + elementId).children("option:contains('" + option + "')").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Caramba . Please see my recent edit . In your jfiddle , look like it is getting refreshed . But see my jfiddle , it is not getting refreshed. The DOM is updated properly but it is not getting reflected in browser UI.

Comment: @JavaUser in your fiddle I don't see the DOM getting updated

Comment: Sorry . After adding jquery , things are working fine. Can you please check once.

Comment: @JavaUser what should I check if it is working fine anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
$(elementId).find('option:contains(' + option + ')').attr('selected', true);
```

That will diselect whatever that was selected and select the new `option`

Comment: yes simply looking the text will work in DOM but not reflected in browser.Please see my recent edit and jfiddle

Comment: That's because your jsfiddle seems to be not loading jquery, see this one http://jsfiddle.net/A8Gq4/187/

Comment: How to refresh the html option element?

Comment: My bad, I posted the wrong fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/A8Gq4/187/, that should work

Comment: Maposa , in my Chrome I have loaded jquery but it is not getting refreshed. As I told earlier I am able to see the updates in DOM but not in html page. I am getting some json through server and want to update some porting of html page in this case.

Comment: You can chain `.change()` method to the above line, like so: `$(elementId).find('option:contains(' + option + ')').attr('selected', true).change()`, this will force change visually. Jus curious which version of jQuery are you loading?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106985/discussion-between-maposa-takalani-and-javauser).